# Lifetime issues when refactoring into function with closure back-call

Tags: rust, closures, refactoring, lifetime, borrow-checker

I am writing a Rust application that uses the [`wgpu`](https://docs.rs/wgpu/latest/wgpu/) library to render stuff. How the library works is largely unimportant, since the errors I'm facing are lifetime-related.

In the function that actually performs the rendering looks like this: (You don't need to understand it, I listed it largely for completeness' sake.)

```rust
pub fn render(&self) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let output = self.surface.get_current_texture()?;

    let view = output.texture.create_view(&wgpu::TextureViewDescriptor::default());
    let mut encoder = self.device.create_command_encoder(
        &wgpu::CommandEncoderDescriptor { label: Some("render encoder") }
    );

    let render_pass_descriptor = wgpu::RenderPassDescriptor {
        label: Some("render pass"),
        color_attachments: &[
            wgpu::RenderPassColorAttachment {
                view: &view,
                resolve_target: None,
                ops: wgpu::Operations {
                    load: wgpu::LoadOp::Clear(
                            wgpu::Color { r: 0.1, g: 0.2, b: 0.3, a: 1.0 }),
                    store: false,
                }
            },
        ],
        depth_stencil_attachment: None,
    };

    let mut render_pass = encoder.begin_render_pass(&render_pass_descriptor);

    render_pass.set_pipeline(&self.render_pipeline);
    render_pass.set_vertex_buffer(0, self.vertex_buffer.slice(..));
    render_pass.draw(0..self.num_vertecies, 0..1);
    // Explicitly drop, bc. it borrows the encoder.
    drop(render_pass);

    self.queue.submit(iter::once(encoder.finish()));
    output.present();

    Ok(())
}
```

I wanted to refactor this piece of code into a utility function, but keep the three calls on the `render_pass` object.

The utility function has this signature and does the same stuff the original function did, but instead of the three calls on `render_pipeline`, it just calls the `render_pass_configurator` closure:

```rust
pub fn submit_render_pass<F: FnOnce(wgpu::RenderPass)>(
    surface: &wgpu::Surface,
    device: &wgpu::Device,
    queue: &wgpu::Queue,
    clear_color: wgpu::Color,
    render_pass_configurator: F,
) -> anyhow::Result<()> { ... }
```

And the body of the original `render()` function is replaced with the call to this utility function:

```rust
    util::submit_render_pass(&self.surface, &self.device, &self.queue,
        wgpu::Color { r: 0.1, g: 0.2, b: 0.3, a: 1.0 },
        | mut render_pass | {
            render_pass.set_pipeline(&self.render_pipeline);
            render_pass.set_vertex_buffer(0, self.vertex_buffer.slice(..));
            render_pass.draw(0..self.num_vertecies, 0..1);
        },
    )
```

Seems straightforward to me, but of course Rust's borrow checker disagrees:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/gpu.rs:89:38
   |
89 |             render_pass.set_pipeline(&self.render_pipeline);
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime defined here...
  --> src/gpu.rs:85:19
   |
85 |     pub fn render(&self) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
   |                   ^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/gpu.rs:89:38
   |
89 |             render_pass.set_pipeline(&self.render_pipeline);
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined here...
  --> src/gpu.rs:88:9
   |
88 | /         | mut render_pass: wgpu::RenderPass | {
89 | |             render_pass.set_pipeline(&self.render_pipeline);
90 | |             render_pass.set_vertex_buffer(0, self.vertex_buffer.slice(..));
91 | |             render_pass.draw(0..self.num_vertecies, 0..1);
92 | |         },
   | |_________^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/gpu.rs:89:25
   |
89 |             render_pass.set_pipeline(&self.render_pipeline);
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `&mut RenderPass<'_>`
              found `&mut RenderPass<'_>`
```

(... and a similar error for the `.slice(..)` call.)

I understand that because of the `render_pass.set_pipeline(&self.render_pipeline)` call, `render_pass` may not ever live longer than `&self`. But it doesn't. `render_pipeline` gets dropped at the end of the closure, and `&self` lives on.

I tried adding lifetimes to the best of my ability, and I got the error to change only once when I added an explicit lifetime to the type of the utility function, changing the closure definition to `F: FnOnce(wgpu::RenderPass<'a>)`: (But this error didn't make much sense to me either.)

```
error[E0597]: `view` does not live long enough
   --> src/gpu_util.rs:130:23
    |
112 | pub fn submit_render_pass<'a, F: FnOnce(wgpu::RenderPass<'a>)>(
    |                           -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
130 |                 view: &view,
    |                       ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
143 |     render_pass_configurator(render_pass);
    |     ------------------------------------- argument requires that `view` is borrowed for `'a`
...
149 | }
    | - `view` dropped here while still borrowed
```

#### Update

I got it to work by writing the `render()` function like this: (`Self` == `GpuState`)

```rust
pub fn render(&self) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    fn configure_render_pass<'a>(s: &'a GpuState, mut render_pass: wgpu::RenderPass<'a>) {
            render_pass.set_pipeline(&s.render_pipeline);
            render_pass.set_vertex_buffer(0, s.vertex_buffer.slice(..));
            render_pass.draw(0..s.num_vertecies, 0..1);
    }
    util::submit_render_pass(&self.surface, &self.device, &self.queue,
        wgpu::Color { r: 0.1, g: 0.2, b: 0.3, a: 1.0 },
        | render_pass: wgpu::RenderPass<'_> | {
            configure_render_pass(self, render_pass);
        },
    )
}
```

I think what makes it work here is that I get a chance to explicitly tell the compiler that the captured `self` lives as long as the `render_pass`. But that's only my guess...

I'll leave the question open, if anyone comes up with a solution to make it work without the extra function declaration.

Answer (score 3):

```rust
pub fn submit_render_pass<F: FnOnce(wgpu::RenderPass)>(
    surface: &wgpu::Surface,
    device: &wgpu::Device,
    queue: &wgpu::Queue,
    clear_color: wgpu::Color,
    render_pass_configurator: F,
) -> anyhow::Result<()> { ... }
```

First of, all, you have a hidden lifetime parameter, which can give rise to very confusing errors. Add the [`#![deny(elided_lifetimes_in_paths)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/listing/allowed-by-default.html#elided-lifetimes-in-paths) lint setting to your code to force these to be explicit. (It's unfortunate that that lint isn't on by default.) You'll be required to change the code to…

```rust
pub fn submit_render_pass<F: FnOnce(wgpu::RenderPass<'???>)>(
```

And now we see part of the problem: what goes in the spot I've marked `'???`? The `RenderPass` borrows from the `CommandEncoder` (the signature of [`CommandEncoder::begin_render_pass()`](https://docs.rs/wgpu/latest/wgpu/struct.CommandEncoder.html#method.begin_render_pass) tells us that), but the `CommandEncoder` is a local variable inside `submit_render_pass()`, so borrows of it *cannot* have a lifetime that is nameable from outside the function.

To solve this problem, you need to use a [HRTB](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) to specify that the callback function must be able to accept *any* lifetime:

```rust
pub fn submit_render_pass<F>(
    surface: &wgpu::Surface,
    device: &wgpu::Device,
    queue: &wgpu::Queue,
    clear_color: wgpu::Color,
    render_pass_configurator: F,
) -> anyhow::Result<()>
where
    F: for<'encoder> FnOnce(wgpu::RenderPass<'encoder>)
{ ... }
```

Comment: Although it made sense, it didn't work :(. But by specifying deny(elided_lifetimes_in_path), the compiler directed my attention to the closure: The argument (`render_pass`) is of type `wgpu::RenderPass`, but has an elided lifetime parameter that I need to specify now. I tried declaring a lifetime on the `render()` function and specifying it in the type, but now I get a 'lifetime mismatch' error: https://paste.sr.ht/~tobtobxx/50de8e99c52bff6c169101d4bce09cc067e1e525. It says it expected the lifetime <'_>, but got <'a>. (If it's elided, then why complain?? *roll eyes*). Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work, but it doesn't look as clean as I hoped for, so I'll leave the Q open: The trick was to define a function (not a closure), that takes `Self` and `wgpu::RenderPass` and does the configuration. Then I can write a wrapper closure that captures `self` and use that as argument to the util function. I think what makes it work is that I get the chance to tell the compiler that the captured `self` lives as long as `render_pass`. But what do I know, Updated question.